# Substitute phrase for "no-nonsense approach"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I am writing a biography blurb and I am looking for a phrase to substitute **her no-nonsense approach**

Comment: More detail please.  What research have you done?  What is the context you want to use this phrase in?

Comment: It would help to know what's wrong with "no-nonsense approach"

Answer (score 1):

> Her straightforward approach
>
> Her upfront approach
>
> Her down-to-earth approach